# Looking for the smallest app container which is capable of running a clojure-powered website

Tags: clojure, webserver, raspberry-pi

I'm looking for a program which takes up very little disk space, does not require much memory or cpu power, while it is capable of running a clojure web app.

I'm planning to run it on a Raspberry PI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[http-kit](http://http-kit.org/) is probably the best choice:

- It is very lightweight and efficient (less than 100k .jar file with zero dependencies apart from Clojure itself)
- It is also fully [Ring](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring) compatible so you can use it with most of the regular Clojure web libraries (e.g. Compojure).
- It has great performance and scalability (apparently achieving over [600k concurrent connections](http://http-kit.org/600k-concurrent-connection-http-kit.html) on a PC)

Comment: Do you have a benchmark about its memory footprint?

Comment: I don't have a memory benchmark. But the .jar has zero dependencies and is less than 100k, so it's pretty tiny (at least, in comparison to most application server like Jetty, Tomcat or JBoss...)

Comment: `# some numbers about how fast can http-kit's client can run
lein test :benchmark` :)